# Barrier-Free Drag&Drop Pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, drag-and-drop

In days of ajaxish Web2.0 I wonder whether it is possible to create 100% barrier-free web pages or if there are even patterns to support common Web2.0-practices.

What came to my mind is drag&drop. Is there an all-round solution for this or does it depend highly on the way the technique is used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and Drop instantly creates a barrier - the user has to be capable of performing the action, and they need a device capable of letting them.

Examples of users who are likely to have problems with drag and drop in webpages include:

- People who are blind
- People who suffer from arthritis
- People who have JavaScript turned off
- People who are using an iPhone

In general terms, a solution that lets people pick a source element and then pick a destination element will make it accessible, however you should look at the particular use case each time so you can pick the best solution rather then a generic one.